# Nuxt.js POSTing to a parse server inside asyncData results in cross-origin error

Tags: javascript, express, parse-server, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt to build a client that fetches data from parse server.
In my index.vue I am sending request to the parse server inside asyncData. I am on development server serving at localhost:3000.

Here is a part of my index.vue file

```
export default {
    asyncData() {
        let user = new Parse.User()

        user.set('email', 'email@company.com')
        user.set('username', 'sample_user')
        user.set('created_at', '2018-04-04')
        user.set('updated_at', '2018-04-04')
        return user
          .save()
          .then(response => console.log(response))
       }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on my *Chrome* browser's (I am using Chrome by the way) console

`POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 410
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.parse.com/1/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I tried adding cors as middleware to server/index.js as follows

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

But nothing changed. How can I overcome the 'ever-present' Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

**UPDATE After @Nicolas Pennec's answer**

I tried creating a sign in with google feature and changed my nuxt.config.js configuration and added the following:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      google: {
        client_id:
          '****.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    }
  }
```

It authenticates with google properly and redirects back to my login route. It encounters error and shows the following on the console:

```
OPTIONS https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo 403
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
[ERROR] [AUTH] Error: Network Error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CORS warning from `http://localhost:3000/` to `https://api.parse.com/` is not an issue, but a normal security warning. It does not depend on Nuxt but on your browser.

I recommend you to use the official `@nuxt/axios` module + the `proxy` configuration to easily avoid CORS issue.

See https://axios.nuxtjs.org && https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module

---

1/ Install module:

```
yarn add @nuxtjs/axios
```

or

```
npm install @nuxtjs/axios
```

2/ Configure module in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api': 'https://api.parse.com/'
  },

  // ...
}
```

3/ Call through axios proxy

Update your `Parse` configuration to call `POST http://localhost:3000/api/1/users` instead of `POST https://api.parse.com/1/users`

```
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
```

or with a relative path:

```
Parse.serverURL = '/api'
```

Comment: This fixed the cors case. But now I am getting a timeout error `Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/users from localhost:3000 to https://parseapi.back4app.com/ (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_sy
stem_errors)`

Comment: I need more details about your last issue. But try the `pathRewrite` option on module config: `proxy: {
  '/api/': { target: 'https://api.parse.com/', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} }
}`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4328275/nicolas-pennec) I encountered similar problems when I created a google sign in feature. I have updated my question to explain the issue. Could it be a conflict with the proxy setting?

Comment: @Merhawi I suppose that you use the module "@nuxtjs/auth", right? You probably have to set a client_id or a bearer token (see doc https://auth.nuxtjs.org/reference/schemes/oauth2#usage). I do not know this module well. So it's better to create a new question on StackOverflow.